# Way to Have a Module Level Type be Determined Via Method, VBA

Tags: vba, types

I have a class I use for Arrays in my Visual Basic Application. Its similar to array objects in other languages (myArray.length for example). It works pretty good. Except the array in the class itself is of type variant. I do this so I can instantiate using any array type I need.

But using variant type is inefficient in both memory and speed and was wondering if there was a smart way to define the type in my class so its not variant. But I can't think of a way to do this.

So right now, I have a class module type defined as:

```
private type Tarray
    data as variant
    length as long
    ... 
end type

private this as Tarray
```

Then I have a factory/constructor method that does this:

```
public sub ArrayClass(optional rowCount as variant, optional colCount as variant)
   redim this.data(rowCount,colCount)
   ... other stuff to handle the optional parameters
end sub
```

I know I could add in a data type to my parameters to define on the redim line:

```
redim this.data(rowCount,colCount) as long (or whatever datatype I passed in my parameters)
```

Although this is better than what I'm currently doing, it is still slower than just declaring it as long in the first place.

So the only thing I can think of is to have multiple array classes, one for long, one for double, etc. But this seems rather redundant and against DRY principles.

I was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With standard VBA/VB6 you are stuck with writing a class for each data type so your Variant approach is probably the best you will get for a 'generic' solution.  There may be a solution if you are able to use twinBasic (an up and coming independent replacement for VBA/VB6).  twinBasic allows  generic classes when used within the twinbasic environment.  So you may be able to fully write your code as a excel add in (examples are provided which can be selected when you start the twinbasic IDE).

Comment: An _evolution_, more than a _replacement_ ;-) but yes, that's totally a job for tB generics.

Comment: Hmm, haven't heard of TwinBASIC yet. Will it give us the ability inherit classes?

Comment: Thanks for your response BTW. That confirms what I believed, but I was hoping there was something out there that I hadn't thought of yet.